# Open new page and execute javascript in the same href link

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make a link which will execute a function and open the page `#item-info` simultaneously but I'm having trouble. (I'm using JQuery which is why I have the #)

The part which is causing the problem seems to be the javascript function `updateItem(item, type, stock)`

```
<?php       
for ($row = 0; $row < $arrlength; $row++)
{
    echo "<li>";
    echo "<a href='javascript:updateItem($items[$row]["Item"], $items[$row]["Type"], $items[$row]["Stock"]); #item-info'";   
    echo $items[$row]["Item"];
    echo "</a>"; 
    echo "</li>";
}
?>
```

I think the problems arise with the quote usage but I'm not too sure what I'm doing wrong with them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using the onclick event.

```
<?php       
for ($row = 0; $row < $arrlength; $row++)
{
    echo "<li>";
    echo "<a href='#item-info' onclick='updateItem(\"".$items[$row]["Item"]."\", \"".$items[$row]["Type"]."\", \"".$items[$row]["Stock"]."\");'>";   
    echo $items[$row]["Item"];
    echo "</a>"; 
    echo "</li>";
}
?>
```

Comment: There we go, this will run the function and change the hash, if only you'd escape those double quotes, it would be totally correct.

Comment: Fixed the quotes. Also made the onclick event respect the possible strings that you could be passing into it, instead of assuming they are integers.

Answer (score 1):

Your initial `<a href=` is not closed & the PHP code is not really quoted well within the `echo` command:

```
<?php       
          for ($row = 0; $row < $arrlength; $row++)
          {
              echo "<li>";
              echo "<a href='javascript:updateItem(" . $items[$row]["Item"] . ", " . $items[$row]["Type"] . ", " . $items[$row]["Stock"] . "); #item-info'>";   
              echo $items[$row]["Item"];
              echo "</a>"; 
              echo "</li>";
          }
?>
```

But I prefer to do things like this with [`sprintf`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) to avoid going nuts keeping track of quotes:

```
<?php       
          for ($row = 0; $row < $arrlength; $row++)
          {
              echo "<li>";
              echo sprintf("<a href='javascript:updateItem(%s,%s,%s; #item-info'>", $items[$row]["Item"], $items[$row]["Type"], $items[$row]["Stock"]);   
              echo $items[$row]["Item"];
              echo "</a>"; 
              echo "</li>";
          }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use associative arrays inside of strings in the same way as a string variable. Use concatenation instead:

```
<?php       
          for ($row = 0; $row < $arrlength; $row++)
          {
              echo "<li>";
              echo "<a href='javascript:updateItem(" . $items[$row]["Item"] . "," . $items[$row]["Type"] . "," . $items[$row]["Stock"] . "); #item-info'";   
              echo $items[$row]["Item"];
              echo "</a>"; 
              echo "</li>";
          }
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

When updateItem() is called, use window.location.href. As for the quote issues, use single or doubles quotes around your parameters to updateItem()

Use something like Update and define update as:

```
function updateItem(url) {
// do work updating here, etc.
// ---
// next, redirect
window.location.href=url;
}
```

Comment: Your answer is very vague. You should include code to support it.